# scipy sparse matrix indices

Tags: numpy, scipy

when I print the values of the second row in a sparse matrix, I noticed that the first index is 0 instead 1. See my example below. Why is that?

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import *
>>> a=lil_matrix((100,100))
>>> a[0,0]=5
>>> a[0,1]=6
>>> a[0,20]=9
>>> print a[0,:]
(0, 0)  5.0
(0, 1)  6.0
(0, 20) 9.0
>>> a[1,5]=55
>>> a[1,50]=99
>>> print a[1,:]
(0, 5)  55.0
(0, 50) 99.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a[1,:]` is a sparse matrix with one row (as opposed to the original `a`) and you are printing its first (and only) row.

Comment: For comparison try: `print a` to see all your entries (i.e. in rows 0 and 1 for sparse matrix `a`)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an artifact of what's happening under the hood for the list of lists sparse array. If you print the entire array the indices are correct, but if you slice on the row you get relative indices. Check it out:

```
>>> print a
  (0, 0)    5.0
  (0, 1)    6.0
  (0, 20)   9.0
  (1, 5)    55.0
  (1, 50)   99.0
>>> print a[1,:]
  (0, 5)    55.0
  (0, 50)   99.0
```

I haven't looked under the hood to figure out why this happens, but if you really need to know, the Numpy/SciPy [mailing lists](http://www.scipy.org/Mailing_Lists) are really responsive.